# Edit the cell's content of a QTableWidget in the code

Tags: python, pyqt, cell, qtablewidget

In my code, I've created a QTableWidget with 50 columns and 2 rows.
By executing a function, Python put in cells list's elements that I've created before. But, I don't know how to modify these cells.
For example, I want to get the current data of a cell at (x,y) and add an integer. So I've tried :

```
content = int(self.ui.table.item(X, Y).text()) #I've just strings in my cells
self.ui.table.item(X, Y).setText(str(content + 1)
```

But that part of code, don't work.
I've tried too :

```
a=self.ui.table.item(X,Y)
print(a.data(0).toString())
```

But Python return me :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Could you post a small runnable example that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,hope this will work:

```
val = 21                            # integer value
row = X                             # this is your row number
self.ui.table.insertRow(row)        # here you decide in which row
item = QTableWidgetItem(str(val))   # create a new Item
self.ui.table.setItem(row,Y, item)
```

This will override the value at X,Y index of QTableWidget cell.

Answer (score 2):

if you used QtDesigner to create the user interface, particularly the tables, is probably that you have a instances problem, Qtdesigner create the table (QTablewiget) but does not create cells (QTableWidgetItem) inside the table, these is the reason that when you try to get the item X, Y you got a "noneType" object, I know its sound crazy there is 3 ways to solve these:

1st : you can create the individual items  as @zeb show it

2do : fill the cell on QtDesigner with a value, with this Qtdesigner create the tables items

3th : you can crare each element you need to use on the setupUi funciton as :

```
item = self.table.item(X,Y)
item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " "))
```